# Drag and drop image in Wxpython

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, wxpython, drag, drop

I have created 3 panels in wxpython. One at top. And other 2 panels at bottom in vertical fashion. Panel2 consists of ListControl as list1 and Panel3 consist of ListControl as list2.

I have used wx.ImageList in conjunction with wx.ListCtrl in panel2 and panel3.

I am trying to drag the image from Panel2 to Panel3.
Have used:
`self.list1.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.OnDragInit, id=self.list1.GetId())`

I have used `wx.FileDropTarget` to define Drop target and `wx.BitmapDataObject` in the `def OnDragInit` function.

Piece of code is as follows:

```py
class MyTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, object):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.object = object

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        print(filenames)
        return(True)

    def OnDragInit(self, event):
        text = self.list1.GetBitmap(event.GetIndex())
        too = wx.BitmapDataObject(text)
        src = wx.DropSource(self.list2)
        src.SetData(too)
        src.DoDragDrop(True)
```

**Issue: The drop target is not accepting data.**

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are not setting `SetDropTarget`.

See here, `FileDrTr = MyFileDropTarget(self)` and `Drop_Place.SetDropTarget(FileDrTr)`

```
import wx

import wx.lib.newevent
drop_event, EVT_DROP_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.obj = obj

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filename):
        #filename is a list of 1 or more files
        #here we are restricting it 1 file by only taking the first item of the list
        TempTxt = filename[0]
        evt = drop_event(data=TempTxt)
        wx.PostEvent(self.obj,evt)

        return True


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title)
        self.InitUI()
        self.Center()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        FileDrTr = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
        font.SetPointSize(9)
        verBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        horBoxOne = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        TextLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Drop file here')
        TextLabel.SetFont(font)
        horBoxOne.Add(TextLabel, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        Drop_Place = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        Drop_Place.SetDropTarget(FileDrTr)

        #Bind the drop event listener
        self.Bind(EVT_DROP_EVENT, self.LabelTextUpdate)


        horBoxOne.Add(Drop_Place, proportion=1)
        verBox.Add(horBoxOne, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        verBox.Add((-1, 10))
        horBoxTwo = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.NewText = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Path will be')
        horBoxTwo.Add(self.NewText, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=5)
        verBox.Add(horBoxTwo, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
        panel.SetSizer(verBox)

    def LabelTextUpdate(self, event):
        txt = event.data
        self.NewText.SetLabel(txt)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None, title = 'drop and see file path')
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Note the `target` is the textctrl, dropping a file on the panel will achieve nothing, whilst dropping on the `target` (the textctrl called `Drop_Place`) will activate the event.

Comment: The above code works fine for files. I want to drag and drop image .png/.bmp/.jpg/.jpeg from one panel to other panel. This is where I am facing issues.

Comment: The image you placed in the 1st panel, almost certainly started as a file, which you transformed into a `wx.Bitmap` to place into the panel. Why can't you apply the same transformation again, given the file name?